# Center Responsive DIV

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following code:

**UPDATED:**

http://jsfiddle.net/Zdevq/2/

```
.container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #eee;
  position: absolute;

}

.box {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: #222;
  position: absolute;

  /*Centering Method 2*/
  margin: -50px 0 0 -50px;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
}
```

from: http://designshack.net/articles/css/how-to-center-anything-with-css/

== BUT what I want is the modal box to have a width relative to the responsive container div.

Is there any way to make a truly responsive modal box in a response div ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not use it in correct way, that function has to be initialized on doc ready with use of latest jquery.

> http://jsfiddle.net/n29up/1/

This is the `jQuery` code-
use the jquery this way:

but make sure to add the latest jquery plugin

```
<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>
  $(function(){

    $.fn.center = function () {
         this.css("position","absolute");
         this.css("top", ( $(window).height() - this.height() ) / 2  + "px");
         this.css("left", ( $(window).width() - this.width() ) / 2 + "px");
         return this;
    }

    $(".box").center();   // on page load div will be entered                                               

    $(window).resize(function(){ // whatever the screen size this
         $(".box").center();       // this will make it center when
    });                          // window resize happens

  });
</script>
```

your little `updated css`:

```
.container {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: #eee;
    position: absolute;
}

.box {
   height: auto;
   width: 70%;
   background: gray;
   position: absolute;
   margin: 0;
   left:0;
   top:0;
}
```

Comment: Same problem here: What if the box has more or less content:
http://jsfiddle.net/Zdevq/7/
I tried this out before too, but it isn't size independent, e.g. doesn't auto align to the vertical center.

Comment: then i suggest you to use jquery to center the div, that would be very good.

Comment: not sure how to do it. Also wouldn't that be a bit "jerky" when resizing the window ?

Comment: You are not using this in correct way, that should be like this: http://jsfiddle.net/n29up/1/

Comment: Nice! Use `this.outerWidth` and `this.outerHeight` though.

Answer (score 0):

How about this

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/Zdevq/3/)**

Removed the `margin` from the box and added the `min-height` and `max-height` for the container..

```
.container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #eee;
  position: absolute;
}

.box {
  height: auto;
  width: 70%;
  background: gray;
  position: absolute;
  /*Centering Method 2*/
  left: 15%;
  top: 45%;
}​
```

Comment: sry, I forgot to set the container to take over the whole page in the example, it should be more like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Zdevq/2/

Comment: Unfortunately this wouldn't be size independent as when the Box has more content, it isn't centered vertically anymore:
http://jsfiddle.net/Zdevq/6/

Comment: Is there any way to do this in CSS only?